# Enable GC profiling in new relic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling, newrelic

I have a Ruby on Rails app, and I want to monitor the GC with New Relic. The documentation on how to do this is very scarce.

I already have New Relic collecting data from my app. What I want is to add GC profiling.
Can anyone explain to me how this is done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can enable GC profiling instrumentation in New Relic using one of these calls in your application initialization:

- MRI 1.9.2 or higher: `GC::Profiler.enable`
- Ruby Enterprise Edition: `GC.enable_stats`

For your Rails application, you can either add this call to an initializer in `config/initializers`, or add it directly to your `config/application.rb` file.

You can find more information on this at [Ruby agent: Garbage collection](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/ruby/garbage-collection).

Comment: yeah adding GC::Profiler.enable to config/application.rb did the trick. I have also found out that one can test if it worked by calling GC::Profiler.enabled? in the rails console

Comment: We did this but still get the message **Missing GC timings** in NewRelic